# How to find the number of not unique rows after groupby()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame `df` with two features: `ID_owner`, `ID_phone`, I have to find:

1. How many people have more than `n` phones.
2. Phones shared among more owners, `ID_phone` having one or more `ID_owner`.

In order to answer the first question, I have tried:

```
df.groupby('`ID_owner`')['`ID_phone'].nunique().to_frame()
```

It seems doesn't work because I need to count the number of duplicates rows per `ID_owner` after the grouping. I have encountered the same issue in the second question.

I would like to know if exist a specific method or function in `pandas` for this kind of issues.

The output, for the first question, should be a dataframe with two columns: one showing the `ID_owner` and the second with the number of smartphones that `ID_owner` owns.

Comment: Could you provide an example along with the expected outcome?

Comment: @Cleb The output, for the first question, should be a dataframe with two columns: one showing the `ID_owner` and the second with the number of smartphones that `ID_owner` owns.

Comment: You can use Counter instead of groupby.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you were slicing your table prematurely though it seems like you want to keep the aggregated table. To answer your first question the following code would work.

```
n = 2

(df.groupby('ID_owner').agg({'ID_phone': pd.Series.nunique}).query('ID_phone > @n').shape[0]
```

To answer your second question you can reverse the IDs in the above query, change n, and select the "ID_phone" column.

Answer (score 0):

```
df1.groupby('ID_owner').agg({'ID_phone': 'unique'}).reset_index()
```

or you can use the following way

```
df1.groupby('User_owner').apply(lambda x:x.zipcode.unique()).reset_index()
```

this will give you the output:

```
    User_owner  zipcode
0   Dave        [34567]
1   Donald      [34353]
2   Jae         [12345]
3   Shankar     [23456, 22222]
```

but for count you can use, nunique function:

```
df1.groupby('ID_owner').agg({'ID_phone': 'nunique'}).reset_index().rename(columns = {'zipcode':'count'})
```

or

```
df1.groupby('User_owner').apply(lambda x:x.zipcode.nunique()).reset_index(name ='count')
```

which will result in

```
    User_owner  count
0   Dave        1
1   Donald      1
2   Jae         1
3   Shankar     2
```